# Google App Invite - Message Failed To Send

Tags: google-app-invites

I am getting the following error while sending app invite:

> generic::INVALID_ARGUMENT: com.google.apps.framework.request.BadRequestException: No associated application and/or client ID found for package name

Some info:

- I have tried with both signed release key and debug key
- My application is live on the Play Store

Anybody got any idea about it?

Comment: thanks Tony for the edit

Comment: I have this problem too. I use eclipse. I think I need to set some configurations like clientId

Comment: @Piyush  I am also getting this "Message Failed to Send" notification in the AppInvite activity. In the logs, only this is line is available: "create invitations failed due to error code 13". How did you get this error (in the logs or some exception you caught, etc?)?

Comment: @HamidrezaHosseinkhani Can you show me how to integrate App Invite in Eclipse? I didn't find the document.

Comment: @TOP my packageName was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Just like the error specifies there's no client ID found for that app.

You need to:

```
Go to developer console projects
APIs & auth
Credentials
Create new client ID:
  Installed application
  Android
  Enter package name
  Enter SHA1 for RELEASE OR DEBUG (which ever one you want it to work with)
  Make deep linking choice
  Create
```

I'm not going to explain how to get the SHA1 or anything else as that can be found easily.

There might be more, but as I already have stuff set up and not removing any of it to see if anything else is needed. However, this does solve this error.

Also, the google-services.json file asked to obtain at the developer page for app invites is not necessary to get app invites functioning.

Comment: My problem is that before releasing the app, it works fine but once I sign it and test it, it doesn't send invites; I am stuck

Comment: @Eenvincible did you add both release and debug to console projects? I don't think there was anything else that caused one but not the other for app invites.